Ct 200 lexus 02 sensor 2013
Ct200 Lexus.  I want to replace both my sensors on my catalytic converter. They stole my catalytic converter about 2 years ago. I did not replace the catalytic converter with the original.  Are both 02 sensors the same or is there a difference. What is the difference, and what is each one called. Only has one on the manifold and one after the catalytic converter.
